# Filling a word file and converting it to PDF file using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word

I have a word template. I want to fill it with data and then convert it to PDF file. Is there any easy way to do it with PHP?

Or first converting it to PDF and then filling it?

Comment: on a unix system, not really. On windows, you can invoke Word via COM and fill in the form that way. Or convert the doc to PDF and then fill in the PDF, which is somewhat easier.

Comment: PUNO would allow you to do the same on Linux systems using Open Office

Answer (score 1):

Convert your word template to PDF. Then use

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/

You can import your PDF template and add some content. Then output a PDF.

Check this simple demo:

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/demos/simple-demo/